# D3 mousout event precedes click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am registering the following D3 events to a SVG element.

To explain what this is about, consider that when I hover on a specific area, I render visible a circle element that accompanies the mouse movement over that region.

When I move **out** of that region the circle gets hidden, when I hover back it should gets visible again. ***The objective is to click on that circle to perform a function***. This is where things are not working.

**The mouseout event always gets fired ahead of the click, and since the object gets hidden by mouseout, it misses to trigger the click event**

```
  d3.select(my_object.my_circle)
        .data([{ "my_object": this }])
        .call(FUNC_DRAG)
        .on("mouseover", FUNC_OVER)
        .on("mousemove", FUNC_MOVE)
        .on("mouseout" , FUNC_OUT)
        .on("click"    , FUNC_CLICK);
```

Following are the handling functions.

When I **click** on my_circle, the **mouseout** event is triggered FUNC_OUT will hide the element I clicked, canceling the **click** event that would have triggered FUNC_CLICK

```
function FUNC_OVER(d) {
 d3.select(my_object.my_circle).style("visibility", "visible");
}

function FUNC_OUT(d) {
 console.log("mouseout");
 d3.select(my_object.my_circle).style("visibility", "hidden");
}

function FUNC_CLICK(d) {
 // this never executes;
 console.log("click");
}
```

Ideally, I would need to know how to enforce click events ahead of mouseout.

Comment: What is your CSS like? Do you have `pointer-events: all;` on the `circle`?  For me it works fine if you do that...

Comment: I was not using pointer-events. Thanks for the suggestion. It does work in fact, but unfortunately the element is clickable when hidden and at that circumstance I cannot know when effectively it should not be clickable ( it might be hidden because I moved out of the area but would result in allowing it to still be clickable. But there seems ways I can use this approach. Good hint

Comment: What seems to be working best for me now is using to avoid hiding the object right away duing the mouseout event and instead use a setTimeout( F, 1000, circleObjectAndElse ) which allows the click event to fire before it being hidden.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see the behaviour you describe. If you click on the circle how can there be a mouseout? If you already have a mouseout, how can you click? It doesn't make sense to me based on the code you have posted.

Comment: My bad. I had a few issues:
- the element-cursor that was laying over, once visible, was cutting-off the underlying event and causing a mouseout of the element underneath
- to avoid such issue, I set the style to "pointer-events:visibleStroke" which allowed me to keep control of the underneath element while the cursor-element was right above it. Since the cursor-element was a circle, the visibleStroke pointer event would ensure no events would be initiated unless I would reach its stroke (border), which is never the case since the cursor-element follows the cursor movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering two elements:

- A: an underneath layer element
- B: a "cursor-element" that hovers on element "A" and should be visible and follow the mouse position as long as the mouse is on top of element "A" as well.

In general, everytime element "B" is made visible (as soon as the mouse hovers element "A", it will trigger a mouseout event on "A" and cut the ability of "A" to track movements.

To resolve the above, set the cursor-element "B" with the following style: "**pointer-events:visibleStroke**". This option ensures that "B" will not invoke its own events unless its stroke/border is reached, which is never the case since "A" controls that "B" is always following the mouse position.